# How to get object path in nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the full path of an array of objects by using recursion to loop over the array objects and get their path with relation to the parent, what i couldn't do was the part when the path reset and starts to add the "child" key .

```js
      const data = {
        data: [
          {
            key: 'userInfo',
            group: [
              {
                key: 'street',
              },
              {
                key: 'phone',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            key: 'fullName',
            group: [
              {
                key: 'firstName',
              },
              {
                key: 'lastName',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
// userInfo.street
// userInfo.phone
// fullName.firstName
// fullName.lastName
    let groupPath = '';
    data.data.forEach(function iter(a) {
      if (a.group) {
        groupPath = a.key;
      } else {
        groupPath = [groupPath, a.key].join('.');
      }
      Array.isArray(a.group) && a.group.forEach(iter);
      console.log(' group', groupPath);
    });
```

The finale result should look like this :

userInfo.street

userInfo.phone

fullName.firstName

fullName.lastName

Comment: Are you using recursion here? It looks like it's just a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursion function that can get the paths with unlimited layer.

```js
const data = {
        data: [
          {
            key: 'userInfo',
            group: [
              {
                key: 'street',
                group:[
                  { 
                    key: 'city',
                    group: [
                      {key: 'country'}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                key: 'phone',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            key: 'fullName',
            group: [
              {
                key: 'firstName',
              },
              {
                key: 'lastName',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
      
function getPaths({key,group})
{
  return Array.isArray(group) ? group.flatMap(it => getPaths(it).map(path => key != null ? `${key}.${path}` : path)) : [key];
}

const paths = getPaths({key:null,group:data.data});
console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you can maintain an array of all the groups and just do a couple loops to get this done. The following should do it for you

```js
const data={data:[{key:"userInfo",group:[{key:"street"},{key:"phone"}]},{key:"fullName",group:[{key:"firstName"},{key:"lastName"}]}]};

const groups = [];

data.data.forEach(el => {
  if (el.group) {
    el.group.forEach(group => {
       groups.push(`${el.key}.${group.key}`);
    })
  }
})

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Simple and easy approach with fast results.

Answer (score 1):

Updated logic.

**Issue with current code**

You are over writing `groupPath` with the child node details inside the else block of your execution.

```js
const data={data:[{key:"userInfo",group:[{key:"street"},{key:"phone"}]},{key:"fullName",group:[{key:"firstName"},{key:"lastName"}]}]};
let groupPath = '';
let rootGroupPath = '';
let groupList = [];
data.data.forEach(function iter(a) {
  if (a.group) {
    rootGroupPath = a.key;
  } else {
    groupPath = [rootGroupPath, a.key].join('.');
    groupList.push(groupPath);
  }
  Array.isArray(a.group) && a.group.forEach(iter);
});
console.log(' group', groupList);
```

**Simplified approach**

Use `Array.flatMap`

**Logic**

- Loop through `data.data` array.
- Inside each data node in this Array, run a `Array.map` and return `key` from outer node and `key` from group node.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = { data: [{ key: "userInfo", group: [{ key: "street" }, { key: "phone" }] }, { key: "fullName", group: [{ key: "firstName" }, { key: "lastName" }] }] };
const groupList = data.data.flatMap((data) => data.group.map((group) => `${data.key}.${group.key}`));
console.log(' group', groupList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forEach` method for this, instead of using a recursion.

```js
const data = {
  data: [{
      key: 'userInfo',
      group: [{
          key: 'street',
        },
        {
          key: 'phone',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'fullName',
      group: [{
          key: 'firstName',
        },
        {
          key: 'lastName',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

let res = [];
data.data.forEach((i)=>{
   let key = i.key;
   i.group.forEach((j)=>{
    let str = key + "." + j.key;
    res.push(str);
   });
})

console.log(res);

// userInfo.street
// userInfo.phone
// fullName.firstName
// fullName.lastName
```

---

If you need to use recursion, you can check this snippet out.

```js
const data = {
  data: [{
      key: 'userInfo',
      group: [{
          key: 'street',
        },
        {
          key: 'phone',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'fullName',
      group: [{
          key: 'firstName',
        },
        {
          key: 'lastName',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

let res = [];
let idx = 0;

function iter(obj) {
  let key = obj.key;
  if (obj.group) obj.group.forEach(i => res.push(key + "." + i.key))
  idx++;
  
  //base condition
  if (idx == data.data.length) return;
  
  iter(data.data[idx]);
}

iter(data.data[idx]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flatMap` and `map` in one iteration

```js
const getPaths = (arr) =>
  arr.flatMap(({ key, group }) => group.map(({ key: k }) => `${key}.${k}`));

const data = {
  data: [
    {
      key: "userInfo",
      group: [
        {
          key: "street",
        },
        {
          key: "phone",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "fullName",
      group: [
        {
          key: "firstName",
        },
        {
          key: "lastName",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

console.log(getPaths(data.data))
```